# Mapping an associative array in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to elasticsearch and I would like to map one of my field to an `associative array` structure.

**What I currently Have :**

One product of type `product` in the index `products`:

```
{
    "name":"Nexus 10",
    "category":"Tablets",
    "interests": {
        "1":30,
        "3":70
    }
}
```

As you can see, the field `interests` is an associative array. The key is a `User ID` and the value is `the number of times the user talked about this product`.

Dynamic mapping provided me with :

```
{
   "products":{
      "mappings":{
         "product":{
            "properties":{
               "category":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "interests":{
                  "properties":{
                     "1":{
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                     "3":{
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                  }
               },
               "name":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**What I want :**

Since I'm going to have lots of entries in the `interests` field, I don't want the dynamic mapping to map each ID.

The idea is to be able to look for a specific `user ID` in the `interests` field so that I can boost the score of the result depending on the number of times this particular user talked about this product.

I would like to be able to map this kind of structure.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to change your object definitions.

Having *keys* based on what's actually *values* is problematic, as it will lead to an ever-growing mapping and thus cluster state. It'll also lead to quirky searches.

This is a common enough question/issue that I dedicated a section to it in my article on [Troubleshooting Elasticsearch searches, for Beginners](https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/#keyvalue-woes).

What you probably want to do is to either use nested documents, or parent-child-relations. If you update the counts very often, you'd want to use parent-child, as nested documents will cause reindexing of the entire thing. Nested doc will be faster search time, though, and you'll very likely want to throttle the updates somehow anyway.

If you structure the documents like this, you can easily use nested mappings, and you won't end up with one field per user.

```
name: Nexus 10
category: Tablets
interests: 
    - user_id: 1
      mentions: 30
    - user_id: 3
      mentions: 70
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your article is very interesting, I'll keep that :D. Just a quick question though, it means that instead of having a script like this: `_score * (interests contains userId ? numberOfMentions : 1)` I'll have to `foreach interests : look for the userId passed as a param`?

Comment: If you use the `nested`-query, you can use e.g. `total` as `score_mode`, to sum the scores of all matching documents. Here's an example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/4a68e0e1e724e0f9e693